# Alternative Layout is not working for Articles

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6

I am using j1.6 and I created a new category 'Category111' and under 'Basic Options', I found 2 Alternative Layouts Blog and List, and I set it to Blog and created an article 'Article111' and included in a menu. I tried both Layouts Blog and List but I am getting same output. How can I change the layout ? what I want is, I want to create a new layout inside a component and changing the category layout should change the layout of the component output.

How can I done this ?

Thanks a lot for your time,

Comment: If you don't get an answer here you can try http://forum.joomla.org/, unfortunately I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create an article (or 2, or 3) and make sure they're published, then create a menu item of the Category Blog layout type and point it to your 'Category 111', the items should show then.  You don't have to link the articles to anywhere if you're doing a Category blog layout.

Under the parameters of the blog layout you can then list how many leading articles, how many columns, etc.  You may want to check and make sure those aren't set to 0 or something odd.

Then make sure your menu item is published, and placed in a visible menu module - go to your site and click on that menu item and you should then see your articles.  Do a total refresh of the page though - in the event you have caching enabled.